# saving the head of received buffer after using recv()

Tags: sockets, recv

i am trying to save part of received buffer in char* variable but it is not working

i am using:

```
recv(sock,buff,BUFLEN,0);
char *head=NULL;
head= (char *) malloc (16);
strncpy (head,buff,16);
```

how do i save part of it (lets say 4 first bytes) into char* head?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for scatter-read with `recvmsg().`

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is not working? Also, can you provide some context as to why you want to do this?